# Magento 2 - Pending Payment order lifetime issue

Tags: magento2, cron

My cron is running correctly and I have configured the Magento 2 pending payment lifetime to 30 minutes. 
This isn't working as stock levels aren't being reset and orders aren't changing in status.

Is this feature working for everyone else?

I'm running Magento ver. 2.1.11

Thanks